# Some Linux Commands are not working under tcl shell

Tags: linux, shell, tcl

I am unable to execute some of the Linux commands in tcl shell.

For example ...

1)

```
% exec "export MIBS=ALL"
couldn't execute "export MIBS=ALL": no such file or directory
%
```

2)

```
 % pwd
    /root
 %
```

3)

```
% exec pwd
/root
%
```

In the first case why I am unable to execute the command ..

This command is fine in the kernel ..

```
[root@6 ~]# export MIBS=ALL
[root@6 ~]#
```

Comment: Maybe it is because `export` is a shell-builtin and not an executable file?

Comment: @user000001's comment points out the problem. Also you say "This command is fine in the kernel ..", however the thing you believe is a kernel is not a kernel. It's merely a shell, bash or something similar.

Answer (score 6):

`user000001` is correct: `export` is the shell's builtin and `exec` performs a kernel syscall to execute the supplied command instead of calling a shell to do that.

So to solve your problem you have to call the shell explicitly:

```
exec /bin/sh -c {export MIBS=ALL; some_program}
```

where `some_program` is a program which should see the `MIBS` variable in its environment block while it runs.

Two caveats about the call to `exec` presented above:

1. It assumes your system has the `/bin/sh` symlink or a real shell binary.  And the shell available via `/bin/sh` must understand the `-c` command-line option.

   If your `/bin/sh` does not do that, use another pathname.
2. A shell process will be spawned by `exec`, then it will execute the script supplied via the shell's `-c` command-line option and then the shell will exit.  You have to understand that the shell variables (exported or otherwise) exist only in the shell process they have been created in, hence the second call in a series

   ```
   exec /bin/sh -c {export FOO=bar}
   exec /bin/sh -c {set -u; echo $FOO}
   ```

   will blow up because as soon as the first shell process exits, the `FOO` variable goes away with it, and the second `/bin/sh` process gets (inherits) a fresh copy of environment from your Tcl process.

   What you should take from this is that you have to set the necessary environment variables *and* call the program(s) which should see them in the same script passed to the shell.

And finally and unrelated note.

If your script is going to be big, it could make sense to not pass it to the shell via its command line but rather pass it to the shell via its standard input, like this:

```
set fd [open {|/bin/sh} r+]
puts $fd {
  set -e -u
  echo test
  cat /path/to/whatever
  ...
}
# Read the shell's response
set out [read $fd]
# The following call will throw an exception if the shell
# exits with a non-zero exit code or wrote something to its
# standard error stream.  You might want to [catch] it.
close $fd
```

**Update** to include the suggestion of Donal Fellows: the corollary to the second caveat above is that if you modify the environment of your own process (which hosts the Tcl interpreter) and then run your target program using `exec` the spawned process will inherit that environment variable you've installed into the environment block of your own process.  Hence this should also do the trick:

```
set ::env(MIBS) ALL
exec some_program
```

Comment: You should also mention `set env(MIBS) ALL; exec some_program`

Comment: @DonalFellows, yeah, neat addition I admit!

Comment: Note that while `export foo=bar` works in most modern shells, it does not work in all shells. Especially if you're calling /bin/sh you may have to `foo=bar; export foo`. When calling a program, you can put variables into its environment by declaring them before the command: `FOO=BAR myprog` (with no semicolon in between)

Comment: @glenn Yes, but setting the variables in Tcl works in all versions (well, going two decades back!) and for modern systems you can use `/usr/bin/env` to process environment settings before starting the program. Many minor variations on the basic thing are possible, but there are basic restrictions: in particular, parent processes _never_ see changes made by children (unless they look in the right spot in `/proc` of course).

Comment: ...and by the way one can just set the variables directly in a call to a program: `FOO=bar QUUX=baz some_program` -- only `some_program` will see them then, but it removes the problem of `export`. Should work in any POSIX-compatible shell, I believe.